# Regex for Input Validation in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need a Regex to accept the input only following possible cases like

1.It start with characters only [a-zA-Z]

2.It may contains numbers but it may not repeated 3 or moretimes.

**Example**:

akjsjdfljsfjl133113 Valid

123123sfsf        not valid

asfsdf1111asdf      notvalid
adf111              not valid

I have tried this code

```
$input_line="sfjs123232";
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z](\d)\1{2,}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Comment: Why is `adf111` not valid?

Comment: because 1 is repeated 3 times

Comment: Rule 2 was that it may not be repeated 3 or more times.

Comment: FYI, they may be gently pulling your leg: strictly speaking, `repeated three times` means that it is present four or more times (the first instance, then the three repeats.) :)

Comment: Is `a121212121212` acceptable? The digits 1 and 2 are repeated many times in the string. If it is acceptable and you only meant not repeated consecutively, then I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **Negative Lookahead** here.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?!.*(\d)\1{2,}).)*$
```

See [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/kD1aL1)

Regular expression

```
^                the beginning of the string
[a-zA-Z]+        any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more times)
(?:              group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
 (?!             look ahead to see if there is not:
  .*             any character except \n (0 or more times)
  (              group and capture to \1:
   \d            digits (0-9)
  )              end of \1
   \1{2,}        what was matched by capture \1 (at least 2 times)
  )              end of look-ahead
  .              any character except \n
 )*              end of grouping
$                before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: What about `a121212121212`? Your regex matches that. But I probably misunderstood the problem: I thought it was about digits not appearing 3 times `anywhere` in the string. This is the problem that I don't know how to solve without using infinite lookbehinds (not available in PHP).

Comment: I see that your interpretation was right: he said that  `akjsjdfljsfjl133113` is a valid string, even though it has 3 1s. +1 :)

Comment: @zx81 He meant the same digit repeated 3 times as in `abc111def`